# Captcha MVC 4 refresh button is is not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, captcha

I am using Captcha Mvc 4.0 (Vyacheslav)

Here is my code:

```
@Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter the text shown in imag"
                , 5, "Is required field.", false)
```

And here is the problem:

It is working smooth but refresh button is not showing, and it is due to `style="display:none;"`

```
<a href="#CaptchaImage" id="5f88fe4e11e743c6a8a8430de57cfcff"  
  onclick="______f9192ce4675540129ec6f99adc316d82________()"   
  style="display:none;">Refresh</a>
```

How to make it visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery file need to be loaded before that line

```
@Html.Captcha(....
```

And everything work smooth!

Comment: Add js file to page ::: @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/captcha.js")

Answer (score 5):

In the code he does a .show() which only works if jquery is loaded.  To fix this either import jquery before calling the method or do the following which will separate out the markup and the script.

```
@{
    var captcha = @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter the text shown in imag"
                , 5, "Is required field.", false)
}

@captcha.RenderMarkup()

@section scripts
{
    @captcha.RenderScript()
}
```

Comment: @captcha.RenderMarkup() is nothing, but thanks for answering, I fixed it.